# CMake: How do I ensure a file is created before reading it to a variable?

Tags: cmake

I want to read the current git commit hash into a variable and generate `version.h` out of it. This command depends on my main target as a pre-build command, because `version.h` must be generated before build:

```
# Get the current git commit
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${MY_MAIN_TARGET} PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD > git-commit.txt
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

This works fine. Now, I want to read that into a variable:

```
file(READ "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/git-commit.txt" GIT_COMMIT)
```

Then generate version.h (this template uses `${GIT_COMMIT}` variable):

```
configure_file(version.h.in "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.h" @ONLY)
```

Question is: how can I make this file read and `configure_file()` commands happen only after the `git-commit.txt` has been created? Is there a way to make a custom command/target that just runs CMake script code?

There's also `execute_process()` which can read into a variable directly, but it doesn't have `DEPENDS`.

Comment: File modifications, given by `file()` and `configure_file` commands, are performed immediately, at **configuration stage**. This stage **preceeds** a **build stage**, when commands specified in `add_custom_command` are executed. "Is there a way to make a custom command/target that just runs CMake script code?" - With *COMMAND* like `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P <script>` you may execute given CMake script in **script mode**, in that mode commands `file()` and `configure_file()` works as usual.

Comment: Right. I was just trying making too complicated a contraption.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply use `execute_process` like this:

```
# Get the current commit
execute_process(
  COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

..and then use that output variable in the `version.h.in` template.